# Readonly objects and multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, final, readonly

after using the questions and answers of this great page for over 2 years now, I decided to join the community!

Now to my question:

I had a discussion with a friend the other day: We think, that variables which are readonly or are only read by the threads don't need a lock or anything else to assure the right values are read. But what is with other objects like arraylists, hashmaps? Do I know for certain, that multiple threads can use values of any objects at once without problems?

Don't be too harsh on me, if I asked the wrong way or missed something obvious in my thought-process (still thinking about atomicity...). I'm grateful for any answer :)

Comment: Such variable should be declared as final and then yes it is thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the construction of the `Map` / `List` is thread-safe and if the the `ArrayList` or `HashMap` is NOT changed after construction, then yes, your threads will be able to read the data correctly. If new data is added or existing data modified, then without proper synchronization, there is no guarantee that new changes will be visible to other threads.

Answer (score 0):

Either your custom shared data/object need to immutable/writable-once/read-only-after-construction type.

OR

You need to synchronise your collection type.
Either you can use collection type from java.util.concurrent package released with JSR 166 or synchronise your collection using java.util.Collections.synchronizedCollection(Collection obj) function.

Just keep in mind that concurrent collection is much faster and optimised as compared to synchronizedCollection for multi threaded operations.